# PC flash sync adapter for canon 550ex

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash

I'm trying to sync my XTi to a 550ex speedlite with PC cord. I'm shopping on amazon.co.uk and can only find two adapters that might do the job; [Hama](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hama-Hot-Shoe-Adapter-Centre/dp/B00005LEP9/ref=reg_hu-rd_dp_img) or [SC2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Camera-Flash-Adapter-socket-canon/dp/B003LEBPLK/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=1VNVZNUS3MTXV&coliid=I1AWR7F2XGWTMT). Will either of these do the job? If not can you suggest something (preferably something that's available in Europe and  cheap-ish)

The hama one doesn't look like it has any electrical connections on top so I' sceptical about it.

The 550ex has a 3 pin socket on the side, is there a PC adapter for that?

Answer (score 1):

The three pin socket on the side of the 580ex is the external power socket, not a sync socket.  The Hama product you linked to does look like it has no data connection to the flash, but  [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hama-Flash-Adapter-Contact-Cable/dp/B00006JAII/ref=pd_sim_ph_1) does.  I've used it on a 430 EX II to connect to Elinchrom Skyport radio triggers successfully.  It worked well, but mounting can be an issue depending on where/how you are holding the flash, as it has no tripod style screw fitting in the bottom of it.  I solved that issue by mounting it into a Canon OC-E3 cable which then mounted on a tripod/lightstand easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using eTTL, (where the flash talks to the camera as it fires) you need a Canon cord, or one designed specifically for Canon eTTL. Google "Canon OC-E3 EOS Dedicated TTL Off-Camera Shoe Cord" and you will find them. Or look at flashzebra.com

The SC2 seems to be a Nikon-style cord, that won't give you eTTL at all. Its for their CLS system.

Comment: OC-e3 clones seem to all be vey short (<5feet), I need something 15ft+. Is there an engineering constraint which doesn't allow for longer ettl cords?

Comment: Not at all. Just talk to the folks at http://flashzebra.com/